# How to Simplify $\prod_{k=1}^{p-1}k^{2k-p-1}$

Tags: number-theory, products

I've been trying to complete a problem recently, and have been bashing my head against this particular product
$$Q(p)=\prod_{k=1}^{p-1}k^{2k-p-1}$$

The problem states that for any prime $p$, $Q(p)\ \epsilon\ \mathbb{N}$

And while the "$-p-1$" can be simplified into $\frac{1}{((p-1)!)^{p+1}}$, I can't at all make progress with the part that is $k^{2k}$. All it gives me is this numerator:
$$1^2\cdot 2^4\cdot 3^6\cdot 4^8\cdots (p-1)^{2(p-1)}$$

Is there any nice way to simplify this expression? My previous attempts yielded far-too-convenient answers that turned out to be wrong. They all really considered the prime factors of each and trying to leverage the fact that $\nexists s \in \{2\ldots (p-1)\}\quad s \mid p$.

Comment: Your product needs motivation. Where does it come from, what larger problem would be aided by knowing your product, etc.

Comment: *Mathematica* gives:  $$A^2 \Gamma (p)^{-p-1} e^{2 \zeta ^{(1,0)}(-1,p)-\frac{1}{6}}$$, which involves the gamma, zeta, and Gleisher functions... so this is rather difficult!

Comment: @WinterSand Welcome to Math SE. FYI, using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cprod_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5E%7Bp-1%7Dk%5E%7B2k-p-1%7D%24&p=1), I found the somewhat related [Proofs of identity for product of binomial coefficients](/q/964267), with this asking about $\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{k}=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}k^{2k-n}$, but where the powers on the RHS are $1$ larger than what you're dealing with.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork. Just for the fun : make $p=10$ and evaluate the result. What do we do with the "small" imaginary part ? Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there is a simple closed form. However, you can express it using the [$K$-function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/K-Function.html) or the [Barnes $G$-function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BarnesG-Function.html) ($+$ the gamma function):
$$
\prod\limits_{k = 1}^{p - 1} {k^{2k - p - 1} }  = \frac{1}{{(\Gamma (p))^{p + 1} }}\left( {\prod\limits_{k = 1}^{p - 1} {k^k } } \right)^2  = \frac{{K^2 (p)}}{{(\Gamma (p))^{p + 1} }} = \frac{{(\Gamma (p))^{p - 3} }}{{G^2 (p)}} = \frac{{(\Gamma (p))^{p - 1} }}{{G^2 (p + 1)}}.
$$